# AlertDialog unit testing - java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: android, junit, static, android-alertdialog

I have an activity `MyActivity.java` in which I am generating an `AlertDialog` using `AlertDialog.Builder(this);`.
Now I am trying to write a unit test (`junit`) for `MyActivity.java` by treating is as a simple java class and creating shadow classes for Android's framework classes.
When I try to run the test, I get an error while trying to instantiate the class : `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack`

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/domain/myApp/MyActivity.myMethod()V @31: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'com/domain/myApp/MyActivity' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'android/content/Context'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @31
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/domain/myApp/MyActivity', 'android/content/res/Resources' }
    stack: { uninitialized 26, uninitialized 26, 'com/domain/myApp/MyActivity' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 120f 123a b800 112a b400 03c6 000a 120f
    0x0000010: 123b b800 3c2a b600 184c bb00 3d59 2ab7
    0x0000020: 003e 4d2a 2c2b 123f b600 40b6 0041 2b12
    0x0000030: 42b6 0040 b600 432b 1244 b600 402a b700
    0x0000040: 45b6 0046 2b12 47b6 0040 bb00 4859 2ab7
    0x0000050: 0049 b600 4abb 004b 592a b700 4cb6 004d
    0x0000060: b600 4eb5 0003 2ab4 0003 b600 4f2a b400
    0x0000070: 0312 51b6 0052 c000 534e 2db6 0054 57b1
    0x0000080:                                        
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@21)


    at com/domain/myApp/MyActivityTest.before(MyActivityTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

From what I researched, this error is happening because I am trying to reference `this` in a static context (`AlertDialog.Builder`). So basically I am trying to reference `MyActivity` before it has been fully constructed.

I figured if in my `AlertDialog`'s shadow class I made `AlertDialog.Builder` class non-static, the problem would not occur during test. But that is not the case. Does anyone have any clue how can I get a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you must have a shadow class for `Activity`. 
The actual `Activity` class extends `ContextThemeWrapper` class which extends `ContextWrapper` class which extends the abstract `Context` class.
Just create a shadow `Context` class and use that to extend your shadow `Activity` class.

This whole error is basically incompatible types error.